# Data send to ASP.NET is wrong REACT

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, ajax, fetch-api, form-data

I wrote a function to connect to ASP. Generaly is working. But it don't work when I want to sort list. When object is {Id : id, Type : type} and this same data is in formData. I looked for. On start and and of function. But in ASP I have id=0 nevermind what is in object.

P.S. It's working via postman

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Sort([Bind("Id")] int idW, [Bind("Type")] string type)
    {
        
    }
```

In other like: data is ok in elementNew

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Edit([Bind("Id,Name,Type,IdW")] Element elementNew)
    {}
```

async function POST(adres, object) {
const formData = new FormData()

```
for (var i in object){
    
    formData.append(i, object[i]);
}

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
};
try{
 await fetch(adres, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
        data: data
    })).then(res => {
       ...
    }));
}
catch(err){
   ;
}
```

Comment: If you want to send a single object it probably makes a lot more sense to send it as JSON than FormData

Comment: How to get data from Json in http post in ASP.NET?

Comment: Asp.net should bind the data to your model automatically if the structure matches

Comment: Okey but why is 0 when React send somthingelse. In other function is ok. ?????

Comment: Probably it can't bind your FormData to the model properly. But you didn't actually explain clearly which function is working and which one isn't? Nor did you show what data you actually sent. So it's hard to give specific help without specific details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this place [Bind("Id")] int idW must be id and it's work. Soryt for problem, but I mind is only name.

But I already know is name in query, and bind check is same like in model. Yes?